# Print to pdf without margins

Tags: windows-7, pdf, print-to-pdf

I have a site that generates barcodes for printing. These are to be printed using a label printer (think a Zebra label printer) at exactly 1.25" x 2.50".

From the "print" window in my browser I'm able to specify the correct page size, but I'm unable to specify the margins. It's creating a margin of about 0.50", I need it to be much less than that.

EDIT: more confusion: margins are set to 0 in the print server properties, but the pdf created still has margins.

Here's a screengrab of my print server settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can view the full page in web browser (Chrome or Citrio as they let you to save pages as PDF instead of printing them) then you can go to printing options in the browser and change the settings you want and then save as the page as PDF and then you can print it normally the PDF file.

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently, but the pdf that's being created has margins. I'd like to get rid of those.

Comment: If you have Chrome or Citrio you can manually set margins.

Comment: Is there a way to manually set the margins AND specify a custom page size?

Comment: Through chrome, no you cannot set the page size but can set the custom margins as shown above. But you can set the page size when printing the file. As in the picture above you can set the margins as you like and then save the page as PDF and then print that PDF file. Also you can set the page to landscape or portrait mode only if that helps.